# How to handle user choice of notification settings permission alert

Tags: ios, notifications, alert, uilocalnotification

At some view controller I pop up this Notification setting message:

> `My app` would like to to send you Notifications which may include alerts, sounds and icon badges. These can be configured in Settings

How do I handle the message's `Don't Allow` and `Allow` buttons?

If the user taps on `Allow`, I need change the label text in the same view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that somewhere in your app you have code like that:

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:... categories:...];
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
```

After doing that, system will show alert about which you are talking. In that moment, app will receive `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification` (you can register for that in app delegate or by `NSNotificationCenter`). Then, after user will make some choice, system will send `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` (also in app delegate or by notification). At that point, check for permissions using code like that:

```
UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = application.currentUserNotificationSettings;
if (settings.types & UIUserNotificationTypeSound & UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) {
    // sound and icon badge allowed
}
else {
    // either sound or icon badge or both disallowed
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below answer has fixed the issue.

When the system level popup message is visible, the applcation will call resignActivity. When you click the **"Allow"** or **"Don't Allow"** alert button, your alert message will be dismissed and it will call `applicationDidBecomeActive` in your `AppDelegate` class while registering with  NSNotificationCenter can be able to change text when user immediate.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"NOTIFICATION_KEY"
                                                            object:self];
    });
}
```